# How to filter mails using received time using vba

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to find a way to filter email based on multiple criteria however i while running the below code i am getting an error  "Cannot Parse Condition.Error at"09". The ReceivedDate is 8/24/2008 9:55:30 PM

```
ReceivedDate = Me.cballocation.Column(1)
Sender = Me.cballocation.Column(2)
Subject = Me.cballocation.Column(0)

sFilter = "[subject] = '" & Subject & "' and DateValue[ReceivedTime]=" & Format$(ReceivedDate, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & " and " & "[Sender]= '" & Sender & "'"
Set Ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set ml = Ns.Folders("MIMUMBAI").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Completed")
Set ml = ml.Items.Restrict(sFilter)
```

Answer (score 1):

DateValue[ReceivedTime] is not a valid condition. You must use a range

```
([ReceivedTime] > Date1) AND ([ReceivedTime] < Date2)
```

Comment: Its throwing an "Condition Not Valid"  Error

Comment: Did you replace Date1 and Date2 with the actual values? What is the exact string that you pass to Restrict?

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed an error in the filter string. Where you used:

```
sFilter = "[subject] = '" & Subject & "' and DateValue[ReceivedTime]=" & Format$(ReceivedDate, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & " and " & "[Sender]= '" & Sender & "'"
```

You should have used:

```
sFilter = "[subject] = '" & Subject & "' and DateValue[ReceivedTime]='" & Format$(ReceivedDate, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "' and " & "[Sender]= '" & Sender & "'"
```

The filter conditions for date and time must be passed as strings - and yours were missing the singlequotes.

Comment: Now its throwing another error. "Condition Not Valid"

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to format the date and time object so Outlook can understand it for comparing with actual values. For example, you can use the `ToSting` method of the `DateTime` structure:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month,
                           DateTime.Now.Day, 23, 59, 00, 00);
string dateTimeEnd = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt");
string searchCriteria = "[Start]<=\"" + dateTimeEnd + "\"" + " AND [End]>=\""+ dateTimeStart +"\"";
```

You may find the following articles with the sample code in VB.NET included helpful:

- [How To: Retrieve Outlook calendar items using Find and FindNext methods](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/11/outlook-retrieve-calendar-items/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method in Outlook to get calendar items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/15/outlook-restrict-calendar-items/)

In case of VBA macros you may use the `Format` function. Here is what MSDN states:

> Dates and times are typically stored with a Date format, the Find and Restrict methods require that the date and time be converted to a string representation. To make sure that the date is formatted as Microsoft Outlook expects, use the Format function. The following example creates a filter to find all contacts that have been modified after January 15, 1999 at 3:30 P.M.

```
  sFilter = "[LastModificationTime] > '" & Format("1/15/99 3:30pm", "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"
```